# BizTalk & WCF Service: Couldn't find type for class System Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I created a simple orchestration to call a WCF service and get response from it. Web service method is very simple:

```
string GetSimple(int value)
```

BizTalk monitors a folder and receives activation message using FILE adapter from there, then constructs proper message and calls the web service. But fails with this exception:

```
Error Description: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Couldn't find type for class System Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.

Server stack trace: 
    at System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(String className, Type baseType, String initializeData)
    at System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject()
    at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject()
    at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject()
    at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject()
    at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
    at System.Net.Logging.InitializeLogging()
    at System.Net.Logging.get_On()
    at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
    at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.GetWebRequest(EndpointAddress to, Uri via, NetworkCredential credential, TokenImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel, AuthenticationLevel authenticationLevel, SecurityTokenProviderContainer proxyTokenProvider, SecurityTokenContainer clientCertificateToken, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.GetWebRequest(EndpointAddress to, Uri via, SecurityTokenProviderContainer tokenProvider, SecurityTokenProviderContainer proxyTokenProvider, SecurityTokenContainer clientCertificateToken, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.GetWebRequest(EndpointAddress to, Uri via, SecurityTokenContainer clientCertificateToken, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.GetWebRequest(EndpointAddress to, Uri via, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.BeginSendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartSend(Boolean completedSynchronously)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendRequestMessage(IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage, IRequestChannel channel)
    at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendMessage(IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage)


Exception type: XlangSoapException
Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
Target Site: Void VerifyTransport(Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Envelope, Int32, Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Context)
The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

    at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXPortBase.VerifyTransport(Envelope env, Int32 operationId, Context ctx)
    at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Subscription.Receive(Segment s, Context ctx, Envelope& env, Boolean topOnly)
    at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PortBase.GetMessageId(Subscription subscription, Segment currentSegment, Context cxt, Envelope& env, CachedObject location)
    at Orch.Orc.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
    at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)
```

**I couldn't find `TextWriterTraceListener`. Where is it? How to get rid of this exception?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a problem with the config file of the WCF service or BTSNtSvc.exe.config. BizTalk seems to be sending the correct request.

Most likely, your config around logging messages from WCF is having issues or BTSNtSvc.exe.config having incorrect parameters around logging.

You may want to call the service from standard .net client to narrow down the problem.

HTH

Comment: I tried. When I call the service from a simple WPF project, it works fine.

Comment: The offending config file element was almost certainly copied from this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203855.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 .  It has a space instead of a dot; should say "System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" instead of "System Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener".